# create a dataframe with list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm starting from a dataframe extract from gprs routeur fleet, approx 200 lines.
Then I make a list of several specific values that I'm interested in, to monitor.
To finish I want :

1 - make a dataframe with my specific value only

2 - write a csv file

```
import pandas as pd

# the extraction
url ="someurl.splash.com"
status = pd.read_csv(url, sep=':', on_bad_lines='skip', skipinitialspace = True)

# then my specifics values
model = status['value'].iloc[2]
SN = status['value'].iloc[4]
OS = status['value'].iloc[6]
CPUtemp = status['value'].iloc[10]
TOBmodel = status['value'].iloc[63]
firm = status['value'].iloc[64]
IMEI = status['value'].iloc[65]
ICCID = status['value'].iloc[67]
SIMnum = status['value'].iloc[67][6:]
SIMappel = status['value'].iloc[69]
service = status['value'].iloc[73]
band = status['value'].iloc[74]
rssi = status['value'].iloc[75]
network = status['value'].iloc[81]
LAI = status['value'].iloc[82]
LAC = status['value'].iloc[83]
CID = status['value'].iloc[84]
LANIP = status['value'].iloc[112]
LANDHCP = status['value'].iloc[115]
WANIP = status['value'].iloc[130]
dlrate = status['value'].iloc[146]
uprate = status['value'].iloc[147]
```

A sample of the data, after the pandas read function (sorry for not putting it here before) :

```
    label   value
0   === SYSTEM INFORMATION ===  
1   Product name    NetModule Router
2   Product type    NB800
3   Hardware version    V3.2
4   Serial number   00112B02AC71
5   Operating system    Linux 4.19.163
6   System software 4.7.0.103
7   UBoot   4.7.0.101
8   SPL 4.7.0.101
9   CPU Rev 2.1 Part 0xB944 Mfgr 0x0017 (1000 MHz)
10  CPU temperature 60.2 degrees Celsius
11  RAM 512 MB
12  Flash storage   4096 MB
13  Temperature 60.2 degrees Celsius
14  System errors   none
15  Hydra   happy
16  === CONFIGURATION INFORMATION ===   
17  Config version  1.16
18  Config name user-config
19  Config hash b460665137cdca6cd35a2a0da93c0c5d
```

Comment: why `regstate` is reassigned multiple times?

Comment: that's a mistake in my prog :/ Corrected.

Comment: So, now you have a bunch of variables set based on the rows of the column "value".  Now what? Did you want to just add those new values to a list?

Comment: Difficult to answer without a real example of the input...

Comment: Does this help? `new_status = status["value"].iloc[[2, 4, 6, 10]]`

Comment: JonSG that's seem what I was looking for, and it's more elegant that doing every line one by one. I just have to add a "label" column to it by doing a dataframe, I guess. But I will try the other examples below too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to test without grabbing the original dataframe, but this should output a dataframe with two columns: the name of the value and the value itself.

```
url ="someurl.splash.com"
status = pd.read_csv(url, sep=':', on_bad_lines='skip', skipinitialspace = True)

val_names = ['model', 'SN', 'OS', 'CPUtemp', 'TOBmodel', 'firm', 
             'IMEI', 'ICCID', 'SIMnum', 'SIMappel', 'service', 'band', 'rssi', 'network', 'LAI', 'LAC',
             'CID', 'LANIP', 'LANDHCP', 'WANIP', 'dlrate', 'uprate']
rows = [2, 4, 6, 10, 63, 64, 65, 67, 67, 69, 73, 74, 75, 81, 82, 83, 84, 112, 115, 130, 146, 147]

vals = [status['value'].iloc[row] if name != 'SIMnum' else status['value'].iloc[row][6:] for name, row in zip(val_names, rows)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Val_Name': val_names, 'vals': vals})

df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: Yes, that's the all way I want to do it, with the two list I can do it properly. Thanks for your answer (and sorry to forgot data sample, I filled the topic with it)

Comment: Last thing, how can you manage the placement in the column ? Some value centred, other left, other right, don't know why ?

Answer (score 1):

Does this sort of approach work with your data?

```py
specifics_df = pd.DataFrame([model, SN, ..., uprate],
                            index=['model', 'SN', ..., 'uprate'])
specifics_df.to_csv('specifics_csv.csv')
```

Replace the `...` with the rest of the names.

Comment: Yes, that's seem work perfectly. And sorry to forgot to give some data sample, I edited the topic with an example, in case of somebody later.